# React Native StackNavigator: Passing props from a screen to the header of the next screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I have a React Native StackNavigator like so:

```
const AppStack = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={{ colors: { background: "white" }}}>
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode="screen">
        <Stack.Screen name="Master" component={ Master } />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Details"
          component={ Details }
          options={{ headerTitle: props => <Header {...props} /> }} // <-- how can I pass props from Master to the Header here
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

The navigation works fine. When I'm on `Master`, if I press a `TouchableOpacity`, it brings up `Details`, with the header component `Header`.

However, what I want is to pass props from `Master` to the `Header` component in `Details`.

Something like this:

```
{/* What I want is that onPress, I want to pass someones_name and someones_photo_url to
the Details' Header component */ }

const Master = () => {
  const someones_name = "Steve";
  const someones_photo_url = "http://somephoto.com/001.jpg";

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Details")}>
      <Text>{ someones_name }</Text>
      <Image source={{ uri: someones_photo_url }}>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values to other screens when navigating by doing the following:

Assume I am on screen "Feed" and click on someones name thus I want to go to screen "Profile" where it will show that user name that I clicked on.

In screen `Feed`

`props.navigation.navigate('Profile`, { userName: 'Shane' })`

In screen `Profile` I can grab that value passed in via `navigate` with:

`const { userName } = props.route.params`

To set this up inside a header assuming your screen options are outside the screen component and cannot access the `props`.  Look into using `setOptions` to configure your header title dynamically.

```
        props.navigation.setOptions({
            headerTitle: ...
        })
```